# How to remove outer brackets from list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list which looks like this :

```
[[[['one', 'two', 'three']]]]
```

How do I remove the outer brackets such that I get `["one", 'two', 'three']`

These number of brackets can be arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

You have a one-element, deeply nested list. You can use a loop to repeatedly replace the list with its first element. Stop when the first element is not a list.

```
lst = [[[['one', 'two', 'three']]]]
while isinstance(lst[0], list):
    lst = lst[0]
print(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can search for a list that contains either multiple elements or a non-list element.

One possibility is recursion:

```
def strip_outer(x):
    if len(x) != 1 or not isinstance(x[0], list):
        return x
    return strip_outer(x[0])
```

I don't think you really need to create a new stack frame for this sort of iteration, so an iterative solution may be preferable:

```
def strip_outer(x):
    while len(x) == 1 and isinstance(x[0], list):
        x = x[0]
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of removing the brackets of list `[[[['one', 'two', 'three']]]]` can be **constantly checking the length of the list till it's no more 1, then finally replacing the original list.**

```py
def flatten(l):
    while len(l) == 1 and type(l[0]) == list:
        l = l.pop()
    return l
```

Using the function on the given list:

```py
l = [[[['one', 'two', 'three']]]]

l = flatten(l)

print(l)
# Output
# ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

To make it work on a **multi-dimensional** list, we can use the above function to get our job done like this:

```py
l = [
        [[['one', 'two', 'three']]],
        [['one', 'two', 'three']],
        ['one', 'two', 'three']
    ]

for i in range(len(l)):
    l[i] = flatten(l[i])

print(l)
# Output
# [
#   ['one', 'two', 'three'],
#   ['one', 'two', 'three'],
#   ['one', 'two', 'three']
# ]
```

Note: This approach will specifically work on multi-dimensional lists. Using this approach for a datatype other than list will result in an error.